# PHP, deleting a category from unlimited category table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know what is the best way to achieve deleting a category (with all sub categories) from unlimited category table.

I was planing to go with;

- Delete the category and sub-categories.
- Since it is unlimited category system, in the end run another function to clear categories which has no parent_id records in the table.

  Is there any other, preferably more elegant way to achieve this?

**Edit:**
My category table's structure

```
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["parent_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["siteID"]=>
  NULL
  ["memberGroups"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  NULL
  ["language"]=>
  NULL
  ["protectDelete"]=>
  NULL
  ["typeID"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Thank you for your time and concern.

Comment: Please can you post up the structure of your table `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable;`

Comment: I just need to logic, I don't need codes, but if that will help, give me a minute (:

Comment: `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = X OR parent_id = X;` or turn on `Cascade Delete`.

Comment: @Ben L.: This will cost. My first idea was to take all the ids in an array with a function, later loop and delete them. I also had to consider, this is not a new project, it will replace the old one and lately, I have daily over 100.000 new data added or updated in my database and I'm planing to make the whole system multi-website style which means more load on server. Such action will be really expensive for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the concern is in deleting a record upon which many other records have a referential constraint, perhaps a strict delete isn't the right approach.

Instead, maybe try a "soft delete" where instead of deleting the record you'd set some flag on the record (such as an IsActive bit/tinyint field being set to `false` or `0`).  The logic surrounding the database would then need to know to filter on this field.  The filtering is particularly easy if all of the data access is done through stored procedures or through a central data access layer in code, because the filter can then be transparent to the rest of the application.

It's a little more logic/work, but note the added benefits here:

- Deletes are very fast, regardless of referential constraints on child records
- Deletes are not permanent and are very easily recoverable
- Deletes don't necessarily have to cascade (child records can still be active and orphaned, depending on the logic for those particular entities)

Comment: Hello David, your logic gave me a good idea. When I click delete my system is asking what to do with child records and all the content they have. Either way I can mark them to put them in category later or simply delete them. My website has over 700mb mysql database currently. My new system is at least 10 times more advanced so it has more tables (tried to minimize as much as I can). I made a bot (working with cron) to clean-up old unnecessary data to keep my database as clean and as small as possible.

Comment: @Pixeler: If I'm following you correctly, you'd use this as sort of a "delayed delete" then?  That's a pretty good idea, actually.  Deletes are expensive operations, especially if you have very indexed/optimized tables.  Offloading them to run at off-peak hours in a background process is wise.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. I might add delayed delete process to the crons. I will not have to worry about slowing me down specially if I will do it during the rush hours. Considering this system is multi-website system, I guess this might be the best way to go with it. I just thought this might not be the best way to go with it but seems I don't have much options.